# How can I convert a JSON variable into an array for use in a PowerShell script?

Tags: arrays, json, powershell

I have a JSON variable which i'd like to put into an array soni can use it in a powershell script

```
{
"Id": 118,
"downloadid": 91,
"Filter": {
      "Searchterm": "2022 -rec",
      "Ishidden": false
    }

}
```

I tried multiple ways to formulate it but I can't seem to get it working

Comment: this is an json representation of an object (not an array) so what do you mean? and what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Just put single quotes around the json and call the 'ConvertFrom-JSON' cmdlet.

```
'{
  "Id": 118,
    "downloadid": 91,
  "Filter": {
   "Searchterm": "2022 -rec",
   "Ishidden": false
   }

}' | ConvertFrom-Json
```

This will convert your json to an object. To convert to an array, the json must have an array format, like this:

```
'{numbers: [1,2,3,4,5]}' |convertfrom-json
```